# Will I miss out on anything if I don't invite the three new residents to the island?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

The day Nook's Cranny is constructed, Tom Nook receives a phone call while giving the daily announcement.

When you walk into his tent he's still talking on the phone, and after he hangs up he tells you that there are three people who want to come to the island.

What if I don't want these new people to come and settle? What will I miss out on by not saying "What should I do?" to Tom Nook and triggering their arrival?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without moving in additional residents, you won't be able to progress the game!

That said, there is a way you can influence who shows up for the first 3 houses.

If you have previously visited islands with Nook Miles tickets, you can interact with the villagers there and encourage them to move to your island (even before Nook builds any houses!). If you go to an island and don't like the villager camping out there, you can ignore them without affecting your town.

When Nook *does* build the 3 house plots, any villagers you've encounter on Nook Miles islands will move in. If you haven't asked 3 villagers to move in, the houses will be populated with random villagers you haven't encountered on islands. (Though once the names are attached to the plot, there's no way to kick them out before they move in)

After the first 5, further islanders first "sample" island life by spending time on your island's campsite. With the exception of the 1st camper (as [Riley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/367133/will-i-miss-out-on-anything-if-i-dont-invite-the-three-new-residents-to-the-isl/367143#comment517046_367138) mentions), no one will move-in without your suggesting it.

## Chart of how all 10 villagers are determined

---

**Villager 1** - NO CHOICE - Determined on island start

**Villager 2** - NO CHOICE - Determined on island start

**Villager 3** - LIMITED CHOICE - Meet on Mystery Island Tour and invite, otherwise random

**Villager 4** - LIMITED CHOICE - Meet on Mystery Island Tour and invite, otherwise random

**Villager 5** - LIMITED CHOICE - Meet on Mystery Island Tour and invite, otherwise random

**Villager 6** - NO CHOICE - Must accept first camper

**Villager 7** - FULL CHOICE - Talk at campsite / mystery island and invite to move-in (or build a house plot for random)

**Villager 8** - FULL CHOICE - Talk at campsite / mystery island and invite to move-in (or build a house plot for random)

**Villager 9** - FULL CHOICE - Talk at campsite / mystery island and invite to move-in (or build a house plot for random)

**Villager 10** - FULL CHOICE - Talk at campsite / mystery island and invite to move-in (or build a house plot for random)

Comment: Correction for 7-10: if you build before inviting, you'll get assigned a random villager at 5AM. You also start seeing villagers again on island tours (as long as there is an available house site).

Comment: 3-5 are wrong. You can get a random selection if you ready all the houses at the same time. 7-10 are also misleading. You can invite from islands after you place the house. You won't automatically get randos for placing the house. You don't have to wait for campers.

Comment: I've clarified 7-10. I'm not sure why you say 3-5 are wrong? It looks like you're saying the same thing I am.

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to progress to the next stage of the game. Meaning your resident services tent will never upgrade into a building, you wont get isabelle, you wont be able to customize your town, etc.

Accept all the villagers (and future ones you will be "forced" to get) asap. You'll be able to kick out/invite who you want later.

Comment: The only one you're forced to accept is the 1st villager in the campsite.

Comment: The second part is wrong. You cannot force villagers out. You have to wait until they are randomly selected (either they think about moving or a camper selects to replace them).

Comment: you still have the choice on accepting if they move out or not. villagers leaving at random isnt a thing anymore.